# Is it possible to auto-export logs from an EC2 instance to an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I would like for the logs to be saved into an S3 bucket as soon as they are generated.

From what I've read, it appears exporting to [S3 from EC2 via Cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html) is available, but upon trying it out, the export seems to be fixed with a "from" date and a "to" date.

Are there other ways to keep my logs saved on an S3 bucket?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a role with permission to write to certain bucket, than assign this role to EC2 instance. Then you will be able to export logs from ec2 instance directly to S3 using s3 api. You can write a shell script exporting logs and run it as cron job.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using any third party log forwarder tools like Fluentd or Filebeat + Logstash.

Logstash/Fluentd may trail your existing logfiles and push to S3 endpoint configured in realtime.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html

https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_s3